# Can't install APK correctly on device

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I have built & sign my apk by Eclipse ADT as [it is describes](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard) (export and sign by creating a new key). But it can't be install on real device while an errors occurs, such as "installer package error". I have no Android device & sent my apk to friends by email. I'm using AVD and everyth is fine with it. Any suggestions? Thanx guys.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.XXXX.YYYY"
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.9.2" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" 
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.XXXX.YYYY.ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/main_activity_title" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.XXXX.YYYY.ActivityDetails"
        android:parentActivityName="com.XXXX.YYYY.ActivityMain"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">            
    </activity>
</application></manifest>
```

**UPD**: apk installs good, but the error occurs if choose Open (see screenshot). After that app works fine. But on tablet if try open app it says "App deleted".
[image]

**UPD2**: add supporting [API 4+ meta tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent) for the 2nd activity, but it takes no effect

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.XXXX.YYYY.ActivityMain" />
```

Comment: Just check your package name...

Comment: Are you able to get a logcat of the error? That should show what's happening to the package manager to cause it to crash.

Comment: @Jon unfortunaly my friends can't get the log, they are not so geek users). Listen, what if I publish the app here & then u can test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a duplicate internet permission request on Manifest! When I remove that from activity app was run normally.

Answer (score 1):

Your example was missing the closing `</manifest>` and `android:enabled`. I'm not sure if the latter would prevent a device from fully installing it but the first one would.

I've also had issues using the full activity names in the past, so you may want to try using simplifying them to see if it helps.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.XXXX.YYYY"
    android:versionCode="0"
    android:versionName="0.9.2" android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ActivityDetails"
            android:parentActivityName=".ActivityMain"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">            
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: They don't *have* to be, but they *can* be.

Comment: @Geobits After double checking it looks like the android dev site agrees with you. It's strange though as using them like that has given me problems in the past.

Comment: @Jon thanx for the ansver, but `</manifest>` I just forgon copy that tag) anyway it seems adding `android:enabled="true"` takes no effect

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make sure your device and your friend's devices can install apps that are not from the play store.

This is a feature you have to specifically set, or else apps that are outside the play store will not install.

Here is how to set it:

1. Open settings
2. Find the Security settings (Pre 4.0 it is under Applications)
3. Look for a setting that says Unknown sources, or non-market apps
4. Enable that setting

Everything should work after that!

[Here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22616/android-allow-installation-of-non-market-apps/) is an article with pictures if you are still confused :)

Comment: While that can be an issue it would not cause this sort of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Is "Unknown sources" option under "security" allowed on device?

Comment: I don't know. How can I make my sign key as "known source"?

Comment: While that can be an issue it would not cause this sort of failure.  Konopko - it's not your key that is the known source, it is the means by which the app is delivered, ie from the Google play store.